# Read response headers from API response - Angular 5 + TypeScript

Tags: angular, http, typescript, angular5

I'm triggering a `HTTP` request and I'm getting a valid response from it. The response also has a header `X-Token` that I wish to read. I'm trying the below code to read the headers, however, I get null as a result

```
this.currentlyExecuting.request = this.http.request(reqParams.type, reqParams.url, {
    body: reqParams.body,
    responseType: 'json',
    observe: 'response'
}).subscribe(
    (_response: any) => {
        // Also tried _response.headers.init();
        const header = _response.headers.get('X-Token');
        console.log(header);
        onComplete(_response.body);
     },
    _error => {
        onComplete({
            code: -1,
            message: Constants.WEBSERVICE_INTERNET_NOT_CONNNECTED
        });
    }
);
```

The response of the `API`, when checked in Chrome inspect, shows the header is present.

[image]

Comment: have you expose the x-token from server side? using "access-control-expose-headers". because not all headers are allowed to be accessed from the client side, you need to expose them from the server side.

Comment: If he has it in the console, then yes, he exposed it.

Comment: @HrishikeshKale: You are right. Access-Control-Expose-Headers worked. You may post this as an answer.

Comment: i have posted this as an answer. happy coding :)

Comment: trichetriche, I don't agree. I had a situation where I was adding the header on the server and could see it in the browser console, but the browser code couldn't see it. I had to explicitly mark it to be exposed (in my server code) to the browser because of CORS.

Comment: see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58601675/angular-how-to-get-headers-value-in-the-canactive-function/58602196#58602196

Answer (score 197, accepted):

Have you exposed the `X-Token` from server side using `access-control-expose-headers`? because not all headers are allowed to be accessed from the client side, you need to expose them from the server side

Also in your frontend, you can use new [HTTP](https://angular.io/guide/http#reading-the-full-response) module to get a full response using `{observe: 'response'}` like

```
http
  .get<any>('url', {observe: 'response'})
  .subscribe(resp => {
    console.log(resp.headers.get('X-Token'));
  });
```

Comment: is it same for post method also... i am getting error "Request header field observe is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response."

Comment: Where can I read more about this? This fixed my problem but I'd like to know what's going on

Comment: @KaiCriticallyAcclaimedCooper yes sure here is the link https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/ 

also, there is Github issue https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6583

Comment: I still have problem to read Headers , I found the answer , see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58601675/angular-how-to-get-headers-value-in-the-canactive-function/58602196#58602196

Comment: I could see the header in postman. Does it mean header is exposed or not? I am not getting that header when i use above code @HrishikeshKale

Comment: @sreenivas are you able to send header from your api?

Comment: In postman I could see the custom header, but in angular when i use above code I am not getting it. @HrishikeshKale

The source for my work is https://github.com/shuaicj/zuul-auth-example
When user calls login API he will recieve Authorization token in response headers, Which I could able to see it in postman. While getting response headers in Angular using above mentioned code, I could not see the Authorization field in the header itself.

Comment: @sreenivas can you try to console the response header in your angular application.

Comment: @HrishikeshKale
I tried printing in console. I am getting these fields
body: null
ok:true
status:200
url:http://localhost:8080
type:4
statusText:OK

Comment: @HrishikeshKale Thanks for the insight. According to [definition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Expose-Headers) wondering how risky it is to expose a token to javascript at client side. Thanks

Comment: @Jeb50 if you want your own defined header key from the client, you should always expose it from the backend. also never expose or create a token from the client side because it has more chance of a Cross-site scripting attack.

Comment: Good point. Could you elaborate a bit on `never expose or create a token from the client side`? Thank you

Answer (score 27):

In my case in the `POST` response I want to have the `authorization header` because I was having the `JWT Token` in it.
So what I read from [this](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/5237#issuecomment-239174349) post is the header I we want should be added as an `Expose Header` from the back-end.
So what I did was added the `Authorization` header to my **Exposed Header** like this in my `filter class`.

```
response.addHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "Authorization");
response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Authorization, X-PINGOTHER, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, X-Custom-header");
response.addHeader(HEADER_STRING, TOKEN_PREFIX + token); // HEADER_STRING == Authorization
```

And at my Angular Side

In the Component.

```
this.authenticationService.login(this.f.email.value, this.f.password.value)
  .pipe(first())
  .subscribe(
    (data: HttpResponse<any>) => {
      console.log(data.headers.get('authorization'));
    },
    error => {
      this.loading = false;
    });
```

At my Service Side.

```
return this.http.post<any>(Constants.BASE_URL + 'login', {username: username, password: password},
  {observe: 'response' as 'body'})
  .pipe(map(user => {
       return user;
  }));
```

Answer (score 22):

You should use the new `HttpClient`. **[You can find more information here](https://angular.io/guide/http#reading-the-full-response)**.

```js
http
  .get<any>('url', {observe: 'response'})
  .subscribe(resp => {
    console.log(resp.headers.get('X-Token'));
  });
```

Comment: what should be URL here?

Answer (score 17):

As Hrishikesh Kale has explained we need to pass the Access-Control-Expose-Headers.

**Here how we can do it in the WebAPI/MVC environment:**

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest()
        {
            if (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
            {
                //These headers are handling the "pre-flight" OPTIONS call sent by the browser
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, OPTIONS");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:4200");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "TestHeaderToExpose");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
            }
        }
```

**Another way is we can add code as below in the webApiconfig.cs file.**

```
config.EnableCors(new EnableCorsAttribute("", headers: "", methods: "*",exposedHeaders: "TestHeaderToExpose") { SupportsCredentials = true });
```

**We can add custom headers in the web.config file as below. *

```
<httpProtocol>
   <customHeaders>
      <add name="Access-Control-Expose-Headers" value="TestHeaderToExpose" />
   </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

we can create an attribute and decore the method with the attribute.

Happy Coding !!

Answer (score 11):

You can get data from post response Headers in this way (Angular 6):

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpResponse } from '@angular/common/http';

const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }),
  observe: 'response' as 'response'
};

this.http.post(link,body,httpOptions).subscribe((res: HttpResponse<any>) => {
  console.log(res.headers.get('token-key-name'));
})
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get headers using below code

```
let main_headers = {}
this.http.post(url,
  {email: this.username, password: this.password},
  {'headers' : new HttpHeaders ({'Content-Type' : 'application/json'}), 'responseType': 'text', observe:'response'})
  .subscribe(response => {
    const keys = response.headers.keys();
    let headers = keys.map(key => {
      `${key}: ${response.headers.get(key)}`
        main_headers[key] = response.headers.get(key)
       }
      );
  });
```

later we can get the required header form the json object.

```
header_list['X-Token']
```

Answer (score 1):

Angular 7 
Service:

```
    this.http.post(environment.urlRest + '/my-operation',body, { headers: headers, observe: 'response'});
```

Component:

```
    this.myService.myfunction().subscribe(
          (res: HttpResponse) => {
              console.log(res.headers.get('x-token'));
                }  ,
        error =>{
        })
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this simple code.

**1. Components side code:** to get both body and header property. Here there's a token in body and `Authorization` in the header.

```
loginUser() {
    this.userService.loginTest(this.loginCred).
    subscribe(res => {
        let output1 = res;
        console.log(output1.body.token);
        console.log(output1.headers.get('Authorization'));
    })
}
```

**2. Service side code:** sending login data in the body and observe the response in `Observable` any which be subscribed in the component side.

```
loginTest(loginCred: LoginParams): Observable<any> {
    const header1= {'Content-Type':'application/json',};
    const body =  JSON.stringify(loginCred);
    return this.http.post<any>(this.baseURL+'signin',body,{
        headers: header1,
        observe: 'response',
        responseType: 'json'
    });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I had to do the following to get the headers to appear in SPA Angular application when GETting them from ASP.NET Core service:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("MyExposeResponseHeadersPolicy",
        builder =>
        {
            builder.WithOrigins("https://*.example.com")
                   .WithExposedHeaders("x-custom-header");
        });
});

builder.Services.AddControllers();

var app = builder.Build();
```