# Hosting Ionic 3 & expressJS RestAPI on same Docker Server

Tags: angular, docker, nginx, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm trying to host on a server an Ionic 3 app. The app is correctly working on iOS, Android, and on localhost (`ionic serve`) but it doesn't work once hosted and I'm going crazy to solve the issue because there are no errors!

The Server is a Digital Ocean droplet. On it, I have mounted a Docker-compose environment because I need to put multiple **RestAPI**+**frontend** on the same machine.

Right now on docker-compose, there are the following relevant services (+other not useful for the problem):

- Nginx proxy for ELK stack: only care about the particular port and ask for user and password before redirecting on Kibana **[WORKS as expected]**;
- Nginx auto-reverseproxy for new containers: each new (frontend) container will be proxied behind a subdomain **[WORKS as expected]**;
- ExpressJS RestAPI (non-proxied): already taken care about CORS and other minor issues **[WORKS as expected]**;
- Ionic frontend container: **the problematic one**!

**The problem** seems to be that the Ionic container can not receive all the headers of an API request. During **login** request the server sends me back an **Authorization** and a **refreshToken** header and I need them for the further request!

I'll attach some images to better explain what I mean:

**EXPECTED BEHAVIOUR (happens on localhost)**

**XHR POST from Chrome**:

[image]

**Console Log from Ionic**:

[image]

**STRANGE BEHAVIOUR (happens on hosted ionic)**

**XHR (preamble request)**:

[image]

**XHR POST from Chrome**:

[image]

**Console Log from hosted-Ionic**:

[image]

Why the `console.log` from hosted-ionic don't receive/show the headers I want?

**IONIC CODE of the request (function -> to request)**

- **login.ts**

  ```
  local_login(){
      console.log('dati inviati = user: ',this.user);

      this.req.local_login(this.user).then(data => {
        this.spinnerDialog.hide();
        if(data['status'] == 200){
          console.log('Ok => HomePage')
          this.goToPage("HomePage")
        }
        else {
          console.log('Login fallito => LoginPage')
          this.goToPage("LoginPage")
        }
      });

    }
  ```
- **request.ts**

  ```
  local_login(body) {
      return new Promise(resolve => {
          let headers = new Headers();
          headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
          headers.append('Authorization', this.commonVar.jwt);// EMPTY var
          headers.append('refreshToken', this.commonVar.rjwt);// EMPTY var
          this.http.post(this.site+':'+this.port+'/api/'+this._v+'/auth/local/login', body, {headers: headers})
          .subscribe((data) => {
            console.log('data >>>',data);

            data['_body'] = JSON.parse(data['_body']);
            if(data['status'] === 200){
              this.commonVar.jwt = data.headers.get('Authorization');
              console.log('Local >>>',data.headers.get('Authorization'))
              console.log('Storage >>>',this.commonVar.jwt)

              this.commonVar.rjwt = data.headers.get('refreshToken');
              console.log('Local >>>',data.headers.get('refreshToken'))
              console.log('Storage >>>',this.commonVar.rjwt)

              this.commonVar.user = JSON.stringify(data['_body']['data']);
              console.log('USER by Login =>',this.commonVar.user);
              console.log('login OK');
            }
            else {
              //TODO: handling error login
            }
            resolve(data);
          },error => {
            //TODO: handling error login
            console.error(error);
          });
      });
    }
  ```

As you can see the console log of **data** (the response) is complete only on the localhost. But from chrome xhr i can see all the headers. Also, the console log of a single header doesn't work (`null`).

It seems like the code doesn't wait before the `console.log` but this is not possible. I tried also the promise form of the HTTP module with no luck.

Maybe the problem is related to Docker?

I tried to execute the Ionic container in these ways:

- serving the **www** folder through both dedicated or shared nginx instance.
- serving the **platform/browser/www** same way as above.
- executing **ionic serve** with various flag combination.

All these ways reproduce the same problem.

Initially, I was using `localStorage` through indexedDB and I thought it was the problem. So I also tried to remove it (as you can see how I use shared vars) but the problem is still there.

If I forgot something please ask.

Thanks to anyone can point me in the right direction!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48184742/7357329) I was pointed in the right direction.

The problem wasn't ionic by itself, instead it was about the Rest server's CORS configuration. I configured everything I needed about headers for  incoming connection but I forgot to configure it for outgoing ones.

Just in case someone will have the same problem:

**This was my previous configuration on ExpressJS about CORS:**

```
const express = require('express');
var app = express();

[...]

var allowCrossDomain = function (req, res, next) {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type,Authorization,refreshToken');
  next();
};

[...]

app.use(allowCrossDomain);
```

**And after the correction:**

```
const express = require('express');
var app = express();

[...]

var allowCrossDomain = function (req, res, next) {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type,Authorization,refreshToken');
  res.header('Access-Control-Expose-Headers', 'Content-Type,Authorization,refreshToken');
  /* ^^^ This was the needed line! ^^^         ^^^ here you put your custom headers ^^^ */
  next();
};

[...]

app.use(allowCrossDomain);
```

Hope this can help someone else