# Cant get headers of response in angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, http, post, request

I make a post request to a server which responds with two headers that are important for the client: username and access-token.
The Network Tab of the Chrome debug tool displays the following data for the response: 
[image]

I also log the response on the console: 
[image]

Here the headers are not present - why is this? 
My code for logging:

```
this.usersService.registerNewUser(firstName, lastName, email, username, birthday, password).subscribe(
          res => {
            console.log(res);
          },
          err => {
            console.log("Error" + JSON.stringify(err));
          }
        );
```

I wanted to access the header username by `res.headers.username`.

My request looks like this:

```
this.http.post<string>(
      "http://localhost:2002/users",
      JSON.stringify({
        firstName: firstName,
        lastName: lastName,
        email: email,
        username: username,
        birthday: birthday,
        password: password
      }),
      {
        observe: "response"
      }
    );
```

What have I done wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read response headers from API response - Angular 5 + TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48184107/read-response-headers-from-api-response-angular-5-typescript)

Comment: @SiddharthAjmera It is not a duplicate of this! Look at my request that I just added in the question - I set the "observe" field to "response"!

Comment: is this `http` an instance of `HttpClient` ?

Comment: You could try sending a `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` response header from the server

Comment: @SiddharthAjmera yes it is

Comment: @user184994 What should the value for "Access-Control-Expose-Headers" be?

Comment: A comma separated list of the headers you want to expose, i.e. `access-token, username`

Comment: @user184994 Very nice - this works, thanks a lot! Could you please post this as an answer so that I can mark it as solution?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The front end will not be able to access that header unless the back end allows it.

In order to do so, you need to send a `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` header from the backend, and the value should be a comma separated list of the values you want to expose, i.e. `access-token, username`

Answer (score 2):

Just want to give additional info. Yesterday spent on this few hours and was getting crazy.

Once you have `access-control-expose-headers` from backend. And if you just printing response object like this `console.log(res)` or `console.log(res.headers)` it will not show the headers because Angular uses Lazy-loading. You need to explicitly say which header you need `console.log(res.headers.get('your-header'))`

Answer (score 1):

normally the response is just the 'body', while you want the 'headers'. on the res you could use:

```
this.header = res.headers.get('header-name');
```

Comment: But this solves another problem after the headers are received in the frontend because I cannot read the property directly by headers.field - I have to use get!