# not able to access access-token and uid from response headers

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to fetch access-token and uid from response headers of a post request, which looks like this
[image]

this is how i am trying to achieve it from service side

```
signup(postObj: any){
let url = environment.apiBaseUrl + "/v1/leads";
return this.http.post(url, postObj,{observe: 'response'});
}
```

Component side code

```
this.apartmentService.signup(obj).subscribe(data => {
console.log(data);
this.toastr.success('Registered successfully');
console.log(this.citydata,'this.citydata');
```

}

[image]
The method is not giving any response headers. Itried many solutions on internet but nothing works for me.

Any lead would be very helpful

Comment: you must be subscribing to this post request somewhere, can we have that code as well?

Comment: what is the output when you console.log data?  is it a data.data sort of situation?

Comment: data.headers.keys().....can you try this, what is the output of console.log(data)

Comment: @nobalG data has been insterted in image

Comment: Are those headers allowed by backend [see this for more info on this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51971683/61929)

Comment: @nobalG yes they are allowed

Comment: can you try by explicitly writing data.headers.get('access-token')

Comment: it is set as null

Comment: access-control-expose-headers is empty in your first image, I am doubtful if they are being allowed by the backend

Answer (score 0):

Please try once with the below component side code and check whether required response headers are getting fetched or not -

```
this.apartmentService.signup(obj).subscribe((data: any) => {
console.log('access token: ', data.headers.get('access-token'));
console.log('uid: ', data.headers.get('uid'));
});
```

OR

```
this.apartmentService.signup(obj).subscribe((data: any) => {
console.log('access token: ', JSON.parse(data.headers.get('access-token')));
console.log('uid: ', JSON.parse(data.headers.get('uid')));
});
```