# How to get Full Response(Include Header Response) in HttpClient GET call whit responseType arraybuffer

Tags: angular, httpclient

I'm using **HttpClient** whit GET method and the responseType is setted to 'arraybuffer', and I need to get Headers Response because some values needed for me are in the Header.

Comment: I think this post might address your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48184107/read-response-headers-from-api-response-angular-5-typescript?rq=1

Comment: thank you, I need to set observe option to 'response'.