# Angular 6: httpclient does not display headers while chrome does

Tags: node.js, angular

please forgive me if my question seems to have and answer. These don't works for me.

Basically I new in angular 6. I use `http post` to authenticate user. My code looks like this.

```
onSubmit(value){
    const httpOptions = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }),
        observe: 'response' as 'body'
    };

    this.http.post(Globals.authEndPoint, value, {observe: 'response'})
        .subscribe(function(res){
            console.log(res);
        });
}
```

On the server side:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
        res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*");

        if (req.method === 'OPTIONS'){
            res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'PUT, POST, PATCH, DELETE, GET' );
            return res.status(200).json({})
        }
        next();
    });
```

and this:

```
 res.status(200).header( 'X-Auth-Token', 'token-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x').send(user);
```

my request in angular is done like this:

I have found a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48184107/6608257) like my mine, but the answer  is not working for my case.

I think I am doing something wrong.
How can I get token directly in post response.

Any ideas ?

[image]

[image]

**update:**

I have tried the answer listed below.

```
getConfigResponse(value): Observable<HttpResponse<Config>> {
    return this.http.post<Config>( Globals.authEndPoint, value, {observe: 'response'});
}
```

this time I get one header. 
[image]

Comment: This is a bit confusing - what are you expecting to happen, and what is happening that is unexpected? And why are you putting an authentication token on the response to an OPTIONS request?

Comment: @DanielSchaffer I was expecting to have authentication token in my response(in angular 6). Basically I want to get headers that are shown on chrome dev tool directly in my angular response.

Comment: @dmx if it was you who upvoted my answer, then please mark it as the correct answer so that other people can benefit from it in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried reading the full response? Also I would suggest that you use the HttpClient if you're using Angular 4.3.x and above, if you're not already doing it.

[HttpClient reading the full response](https://angular.io/guide/http#reading-the-full-response)

```
showConfigResponse() {
  this.configService.getConfigResponse()
    // resp is of type `HttpResponse<Config>`
    .subscribe(resp => {
      // display its headers
      const keys = resp.headers.keys();
      this.headers = keys.map(key =>
        `${key}: ${resp.headers.get(key)}`);

      // access the body directly, which is typed as `Config`.
      this.config = { ... resp.body };
    });
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I haved tried, you answer, but I am getting only `Content-Type` as header.

Comment: @dmx have you tried out exposing the `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` in your backend? See my answer [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53309992/problem-with-retrieving-headers-in-angular-6/53310116#53310116) for instructions.

Comment: if you look closely on server side code provided, you can see that this has been done.

Comment: @dmx Maybe I'm blind, but I only see `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`, `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` and `Access-Control-Allow-Methods`, but not the `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` I mentioned? If you want clients to be able to access other headers, you have to use the Access-Control-Expose-Headers header.