# How to read server response in Angular

Tags: angular, request, response

I want to read the response headers that came from accessing my website, so for example when I send a request to mywebsite.com it will return headers from aws CloudFront, I want to use one of these headers can someone advice? all I have been seeing is using the following and pass a url to make a new request, but I already have the response.

```
this.http.get<HttpResponse<Object>>(this.url, {observe: 'response'}).pipe(
         tap(resp => console.log('response', resp))
    );
```

Comment: look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/48184742/7321113

Comment: @abhishek you still have to pass it a url, the headers are already there but I want to parse them

Comment: You can use this line for getting particular header value `response.headers.get('header  name what you want')` and make sure it w'll be present on your header.

Comment: @Abhishek how do I set the response variable?

Answer (score 0):

In the Angular `HttpResponse` you can access the response headers by
`response.headers.get('theheader')` and you can check if its there by using `response.headers.has('theHeader')`. Does not matter what kind of server implementation you call, as long as they follow http standards.

Comment: great, but how can I set the response? sorry im new to angular and programming

Comment: You set the request. Not the response. Well maybe you might want too set the response if you would like to alter it before it reaches your inner controls and components. Do you want to do that?

Comment: actually I managed to do it using my backend, send the header to the java backend then using httpServlerRequest I managed to get it