# How to get http POST's response's headers in Angular 8

Tags: angular

So I have a post like below, I send a POST request to login and the response is empty
- which is fine, as expected - but I need to access the 'Authorization' header.

I didn't find any way to access.

```
  const data = {email: "email", password: "password"};

  this.http.post(`/login`, data).pipe(
    tap(resp => {
      console.log(resp); // it will be an empty string
      return resp;
    })).subscribe((resp: any) => {
    console.log(resp.headers.get('Authorization')); // error: Cannot read property 'headers' of null
  });
```

**UPDATE**
Inspired by TheUnreal's answer I added options

```
this.http.post(`/login`, data, {observe: 'response'} )...
```

Now I can access some of the headers like 'Cache-Control'.

Probably I need to express the rest of the headers from serverside

Sam Walpole is right in the comment section, most part of the this question was answered on the link he provided - check out.

Comment: Have you tried `console.log` only the `resp` object. See what's there ?

Comment: @Nicolas Like in the 5th line ?

Comment: No in the last `subscribe` call back.

Comment: Looks like it's been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48184107/read-response-headers-from-api-response-angular-5-typescript

Comment: Error says "Cannot read property 'headers' of null" , so resp is null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add options to the post as TheUnreal suggested, but for me 'response' was needed

```
this.http.post(`/login`, data, {observe: 'response'} )
```

On server side, headers **Access-Control-Allow-Headers** and **Access-Control-Expose-Headers** need to be set and exposed.

A bit off topic but - may help someone - this is how our config looks like in Java Spring

```
configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Authorization", "Cache-Control", "Content-Type", "Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin,Accept", "X-Requested-With", "Content-Type", "Access-Control-Request-Method", "Access-Control-Request-Headers"));
configuration.addExposedHeader("Authorization");
```

Sam Walpole is right in the comment section of this question, most part of the this question was answered on the link he provided - check out.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the headers and other information of the request by passing the following options to your http method:

```
return this.http.post('YOUR URL', PAYLOAD, {
      observe: 'events'
    })
```

Comment: this make some progress but resp.headers - Property 'headers' does not exist on type 'HttpEvent<Object>'

Comment: It does show the request headers. try to console.log the emitted data and check what you need.