# How to get custom response headers in Angular without use of HttpIntercepter

Tags: angular, spring-boot, angular-httpclient

I'm not using HttpIntercepter in my Angular project and I want to retrieve some custom Response Headers in case of error. I tried `{ observe: 'response' }` in my POST API call:

```js
post(url, data = ''): Observable<any> {
  url = this.baseApiUrl + url;
  const headers = this.createHttpHeaders();
  const body = JSON.stringify(data);
  return this.http.post(url, body, {headers: headers, observe: 'response'}).pipe(catchError(HttpClientHelper.handleError));
}
```

but I'm receiving only 4 headers:

`error.headers.keys().map( (key) => console.log(key + ':' + error.headers.get(key)));`

returns

`cache-control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
 content-length: 0
 expires: 0
 pragma: no-cache`

But, custom response headers with prefix `x-` are not returned. Is there any configuration to retrive custom response headers?

[image]

Comment: Check in chrome inspect network tab, for this request are you really getting the header. Also if possible add screenshot from network tab.

Comment: Yes. I'm receiving those headers in *Headers*  tab of *Network* panel.

Comment: Added screenshot.

Comment: What is backend server? (spring-boot, .net etc)?

Comment: We are using spring-boot on backend.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Read response headers from API response - Angular 5 + TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48184107/read-response-headers-from-api-response-angular-5-typescript)

Comment: No. Actually, I have tried the same thing, but it is giving me `undefined`.

Answer (score 6):

You might have not exposed this header while sending response. Your server needs to send `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` header, so that your custom header is exposed to client.

Documentation:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Expose-Headers

In spring boot response,

```java
@GetMapping("/endpoint")
public ResponseEntity<Object> someEndpoint() {

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.add("x-some-header", "some_header_value");
    headers.add("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "x-some-header"); // set this to expose custom header
    return ResponseEntity.ok()
               .headers(headers)
               .body(responseBody);

}
```