# Read response headers in component file Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I need to read the response headers in component file, type of request is post request.
need to access the `X-Pagination` object, but I want to read that in my `component` file not in service file
here is how I tried

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.paginator.pageSize = 25;
    this.endUserReportService.getDailyReport().subscribe(response => {
      console.log('Response of end-user-report: ', response);
      this.reports = response;
      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.reports);
      this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
      this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;


      // here is how I'm trying, but its not working

      this.http.get<any>(this.endUserReportService.URL, { observe: 'response' })
        .subscribe(resp => {
          console.log(resp.headers.get('X-Pagination'));
        });


    }, error => {
      console.log('Error occured while end-user fetching report: ', error);
    });

  }
```

[image: Picuter]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Read response headers from API response - Angular 5 + TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48184107/read-response-headers-from-api-response-angular-5-typescript)

Comment: I already read this question, before posting mine, but unfortunately it didn't helped

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possible Duplicate of [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48184107/read-response-headers-from-api-response-angular-5-typescript)

**Extracted from link**

Have you exposed the X-Pagination from server side using access-control-expose-headers? because not all headers are allowed to be accessed from the client side, you need to expose them from the server side

Also in your frontend, you can use new HTTP module to get a full response using {observe: 'response'} like

```
http
  .post<any>(this.endUserReportService.URL, {observe: 'response'})
  .subscribe(resp => {
    console.log(resp.headers.get('X-Pagination'));
  });
```

**see**: [Documentation](https://angular.io/guide/http#making-a-post-request)

**Update 3:**

The issue is on your server side code.

```
res.header('pagination', 'informationAboutPagination');
    let pagination = 'blablabla'
    res.header('Access-Control-Expose-Headers', pagination);
```

it should be this

```
let pagination = 'blablabla'
res.header('X-Pagination', pagination);
```

you had your headers set incorrectly on server side, and you where reading the wrong header on client side.

update your server side code and then use the existing client side code like above which i recommended before.

Comment: code updated. it was supposed to be `http.post` i accidently left it as `http.get`

Comment: also see documentation link

Comment: Unfortunately this is not working, 
I posted a new question with screenshots can you please go through it. I shall be thankful to you in this regard
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59800737/unable-to-access-response-header-in-angular-application?noredirect=1#comment105742320_59800737

Comment: that is due to line `resp.headers.get('X-Pagination')`

Comment: `X-Pagination` is not the same as `paginaton`, simple mistake, good luck king.

Answer (score 1):

```
  this.http.get<any>(this.endUserReportService.URL, {
      headers: new HttpHeaders().set('X-Pagination', {}),
      observe: 'response'
  }).map(res => {
      console.log(res.headers.get('X-Pagination'));
  });
```

Comment: the API sends the data only if I call it with 
`return this.http.post(this.URL, this.headers);`
I tried with 
`return this.http.post(this.URL, {headers:this.headers,observe:'response'})`
but it was not working

Comment: In your getDailyReport() method add the key/value observe: 'response'

Comment: I tried that way too, but still getting the `null` value