# How can i download the pdf directly from the API (Angular)?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I need to download a PDF from an API in Angular.

So, I've written a service to call the API:

```
 getPDF(id:any) {
    return this.http.get(
       `url?=${id}`,
        { responseType: 'blob' as 'json', observe: 'response' }
    );
 }
```

In my component file, I'm calling the service to download the PDF.

```
  onGeneratepdf() {
    this.service
  .getPDF(
    123
  )
  .subscribe((res: any) => {
    let filename = res.header
    ?.get('content-disposition')
    ?.split(';')[1]
    .split('=')[1];
  let blob: Blob = res.body as Blob;
  var a = document.createElement('a');
  a.download = filename;
  a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  a.click();
  });
```

}

after hitting onGeneratePDF , the pdf is downloading but the problem is ....it is downloading the file name as **undefined.pdf**...it should download as name like **user.pdf** and also
i am getting the response headers as

```
access-control-allow-origin: *

cache-control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate

content-disposition: attachment; filename=user.pdf

content-type: application/pdf
```

Please help me on these issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like `let filename = res.header?.get('content-disposition')?.split(';')[1].split('=')[1];` is returning `undefined`... You should try to debug your code in order to find the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

```
onGeneratepdf() {
        this.service
      .getPDF(
        123
      )
      .subscribe((res: any) => {
        let filename = res.headers
        ?.get('content-disposition')
        ?.split(';')[1]
        .split('=')[1];
      let blob: Blob = res.body as Blob;
      var a = document.createElement('a');
      a.download = filename;
      a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      a.click();
      });
```

Please try above code, you wrote res.header that should be res.headers

if above code not works for you, then take look at below link you will find your solution there [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48184107/read-response-headers-from-api-response-angular-5-typescript).

Thanks!

Comment: After adding res.headers also, its throwing same issue.Thanks for ur time

Comment: Can you add your service field code?  this.service.getPDF(123) for this method?

Comment: getPDF(id:any) {
    return this.http.get(
       `url?=${id}`,
        { responseType: 'blob' as 'json', observe: 'response' }
    );
 } ..

Comment: Put console.log() just above fileName variable and console res.headers, and paste here what you will get there.

Comment: headers : - HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(@), LazyUpdate: null, LazyInit: f} @
         headers: Map(4)
        [[Entries}]
        0: {"cache-control” => Array(1)}
        1:{‘content-type" => Array(1)}
        2:{expires” => Array(1)}
        3: {"pragma" => Array(1)}
           size: 4
 [[Prototype]]: Map
        lazyInit: null
        lazyUpdate: null
    normalizedNanes: Map(4)
        [[Entries]]
        0:{‘cache-control” => "cache-control"}
        1:{"content-type" => “content-type"}
        2: {"expires" => “expires"}
        3:{"pragma" => “pragna"}

Comment: size: 4
    [[Prototype]]: Map
    [[Prototype]]: Object
//////////////////////////////
Filename:-  undefined

Comment: Just console.log(res.headers.get('content-disposition')) and console.log(res.header.get('content-disposition')).

Comment: Headers : - null
Header :- Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'get')